# If $B$ is a Brownian motion and $B'_t:=B_{T+t}-B_T$ for a fixed $T$, then $(B'_t,t\ge 0)$ and $(B_s,0\le s\le T)$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B=(B_t,t\ge 0)$ be a Brownian motion and $$B'_t:=B_{T+t}-B_T\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge 0$$ for some $T\ge 0$. Especially, $B$ has *independent increments*, i.e. $$\left(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}\right)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$$ is independent, for all $0\le t_0<\ldots<t_n$.

---

I want to prove, that $B'$ and $(B_s)_{0\le s\le T}$ are independent, i.e. for all $0\le s_0<\ldots<s_m\le T$ and $0\le t_0<\ldots<t_n<\infty$ $$\left(B_{s_0},\ldots,B_{s_m}\right)\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\left(B'_{t_0},\ldots,B'_{t_n}\right)\tag{1}$$ are independent.

---

Since $$B'_{t_i}-B'_{t_{i-1}}=B_{T+t_i}-B_{T+t_{i-1}}$$ and $$0\le s_i<T+t_0<\ldots<T+t_n$$ it's easy to see (since $B$ has independent increments) that $$B_{T+t_n}-B_{T+t_{n-1}},\ldots,B_{T+t_1}-B_{T+t_0},B_{T+t_0}-B_{s_i},B_{s_i}-B_0=B_{s_i}$$ are independent. Thus, $$B_{s_i}\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\left(B'_{t_j}-B'_{t_{j-1}}\right)_{j=1,\ldots,n}\tag{2}$$ are independent, for all $1\le i\le m$. Can we conclude $(1)$ from $(2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $0 \leq s_0 < \ldots < s_m \leq T =T + t_0 < \ldots < T+t_n$ the random variables 
$$\underbrace{B_{t_n+T}-B_{t_{n-1}+T}}_{B'_{t_n}-B'_{t_{n-1}}},\ldots,\underbrace{B_{t_1+T}-B_{t_{0}+T}}_{B'_{t_1}-B'_{t_{0}}}, B_{s_m}-B_{s_{m-1}},\ldots,B_{s_1}-B_{s_0} \tag{1}$$

are independent. Recall that for any two measurable mappings $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ the implication $$X_1,\ldots,X_m, Y_1,\ldots,Y_n \, \text{independent} \Rightarrow f(X_1,\ldots,X_m) \, \text{and} \, g(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n) \, \text{independent}$$

holds true. In particular for $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_m) := \left(x_1,x_1+x_2,\ldots, \sum_{i=1}^m x_i \right)$$ and $$g(y_1,\ldots,y_n) := \left(y_1,y_1+y_2,\ldots, \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right)$$ we obtain (using (1)) that

$$f(B_{s_0},B_{s_1}-B_{s_0},\ldots, B_{s_m}-B_{s_{m-1}}) = (B_{s_0},B_{s_1},\ldots,B_{s_m})$$

and

$$g(B'_{t_0},B'_{t_1}-B'_{t_0},\ldots, B'_{t_n}-B'_{t_{n-1}}) = (B'_{t_0},B'_{t_1},\ldots,B'_{t_n})$$

are independent.

Comment: Can we conclude, that $\sigma(B_t,0\le t\le T)$ and $\sigma(B'_t,t\ge 0)$ are independent?.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, this follows from the above proof and the fact that $$\left\{ \bigcap_{j=1}^n \{B_{t_j} \in A_j\}; t_j \leq T, A_j \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$ is a $\cap$-stable generator of $\sigma(B_t; 0 \leq t \leq T)$ and $$\left\{ \bigcap_{j=1}^n \{B'_{t_j} \in A_j\}; t_j \geq 0, A_j \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$ is a $\cap$-stable generator of $\sigma(B'_t; t \geq 0)$.

Comment: How does that help to prove the statement?

Comment: @0xbadf00d The following statement is well-known from measure/probability theorem: Suppose that $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(\mathcal{F})$ and $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\mathcal{G})$ are $\sigma$-algebras generated by $\cap$-stable generators $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are independent iff $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are independent. Combining this with my previous comment and the answer, proves the claim.

Comment: I know the statement in your last comment. But I don't understand why you're using *these* generators (It is not obvious to me, that we know, that these generators are independent). Let me suggest, other generators:

Comment: Let $$\mathcal{G}_I:=\sigma(B_i,i\in I)\;\;\;\text{for }I\subseteq [0,T]\;\text{finite}$$ and $$\mathcal{H}_J:=\sigma(B'_j,j\in J)\;\;\;\text{for }I\subseteq [0,\infty)\;\text{finite}\;.$$ In your answer, you've shown, that $\mathcal{G}_I$ and $\mathcal{H}_J$ are independent, for each choice of $I,J$. Now, let $\mathcal{G}:=\bigcup_{I}\mathcal{G}_I$ and $\mathcal{H}:=\bigcup_{J}\mathcal{H}_J$. Then, $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are independent, $\cap$-stable and generators of $\sigma(B_t,0\le t\le T)$ and $\sigma(B'_t,0\le t<\infty)$, respectively. What do you think?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well, actually we proved that the generators I suggested are independent, but if you prefer the ones from your previous comment, then just use them. Nothing wrong about that.

Comment: Just to make sure that I didn't get something wrong: By definition, two stochastic processes $X,Y$ are independent iff $(X_{s_0},\ldots,X_{s_m})$ and $(Y_{t_0},\ldots,Y_{t_n})$ are independent, for all $s_i,t_j$, i.e. $\sigma(X_{s_0},\ldots,X_{s_m})$ and $\sigma(Y_{t_0},\ldots,Y_{t_n})$ are independent, for all $s_i,t_j$. So, you've proved what I said, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Obviously there are several ways to define independence of processes, but, yes, that's one possibility to do so. And yes, I've proved this.